# How to bind the subscribed data into the const part

Tags: angular, observable, subscribe

I have three components, when clicking on the add button in rule-grid.component.ts, it carry some data (like sessions in C#) to another component ruleparam-add-model.component.ts via data-share.ts. Here I have problem in subscription part of the ruleparam-add-model.component.ts

## data-share.ts

```
export class DataService {

   //binding the data 
    subject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
   //get the binded data 
    observable: Observable<any> = this.subject.asObservable();
  

  constructor() { }
```

## ruleparam-add-model.component.ts

```
 constructor(
        private session: DataService ,
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<RuleParameterAddComponent>,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private ruleService: RuleParametersService) {
        this.dialogRef.disableClose = true;
        this.ruleParamAddFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
            name: ['', [Validators.required]],
            defaultValue:['1', [Validators.required]],
            dataType:['', [Validators.required]],            
        });   
    }
 onAdd() {
        debugger;
        if (this.ruleParamAddFormGroup.valid) {
            const rule = this.ruleParamAddFormGroup.value;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(rule));
            const data = {
                name: rule.name,
                defaultValue:rule.defaultValue,
                dataType:rule.dataType,                
                ruleId:+this.session.observable
                .pipe(filter(Boolean),debounceTime(300))
                .subscribe(
                    ruleId=>this.data.ruleId=ruleId                        
                )
            };
    }
```

the problem is near ruleparam-add-model.component.ts-> onAdd()->binding of the ruleId, whose values are receiving from another component.

Is there any better method without using the @Input and @Output, to transfer the data from one component to another component(Here I need to send the Id to another component)

Comment: It's very hard to understand your question. Do you have an issue ? Which one ? What have you tried to resolve it ? Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] on https://stackblitz.com

Comment: the problem is near ruleparam-add-model.component.ts-> onAdd()->binding of the ruleId, wose values are receiving from another component

Comment: Okay but still, my points remain, `Please read How to Ask and provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example on stackblitz.com`

Comment: ok. I will. And Re edited the code again. I will try in stackblitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here I got the answer.

Approach 1: usage of separate DataService, which is working as session in C#(none convensional).

Approach 2:

```
public siteCreateModel:BehaviorSubject<RuleId>= new BehaviourSubject<RuleId>(null);
```